# Show that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Question: A hat contains $a$ slips of paper labeled with the number $1$, and $b$ slips labels with the number $2$. Two slips are drawn at random without replacement. Let $X$ be the number on the first slip drawn and $Y$ the number on the second. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed.

Attempt: $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed if $F_X(x)=F_Y(x)$ for $x=1,2$ (where $F_X, F_Y$ are the cumulative density functions of $X,Y$ respectively). Clearly $F_X(2)= F_Y(2) = 1$ ($X,Y$ are always $\leq 2$). To see the $x=1$ case observe

$$F_X(1) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq 1) = \mathbb{P}(X=1) = \frac{a}{a+b} $$

and also
\begin{align*}
F_Y(1) = \mathbb{P}(Y\leq 1) &= \mathbb{P}(Y=1 \  \text{given $X=1$}) + \mathbb{P}(Y=1 \ \text{given }X=2)\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y=1, X=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X=1)} + \frac{\mathbb{P}(Y=1, X=2)}{\mathbb{P}(X=2)} \\
&= \frac{\frac{a}{a+b} \cdot \frac{a-1}{a+b-1}}{\frac{a}{a+b}}+ \frac{\frac{b}{a+b}\cdot \frac{a}{a+b-1}}{\frac{b}{a+b}} = \frac{a-1}{a+b-1}+\frac{a}{a+b-1} = \frac{2a-1}{a+b-1}
 \end{align*}

but then $F_X(1) \neq F_Y(1)$ and so $X,Y$ are $NOT$ identically distributed.  Did I do something wrong? They are supposed to be identically distributed.

Comment: Hint: For $i\in\{1,2\}$ we have that $$P(Y=i)=P(Y=i|X=1)P(X=1)+P(Y=i|X=2)P(X=2)$$

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
\mathsf{P}(X=1)=\frac{a}{a+b},\quad \mathsf{P}(X=2)=\frac{b}{a+b},
$$
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(Y=1)&=\mathsf{P}(Y=1\mid X=1)\mathsf{P}(X=1)+\mathsf{P}(Y=1\mid X=2)\mathsf{P}(X=2) \\
&=\frac{a-1}{a+b-1}\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{a+b-1}\frac{b}{a+b}=\frac{a}{a+b}.
\end{align}
and, similarly, $\mathsf{P}(Y=2)=b/(a+b)$.